# Use lodash to filter array of objects and check if object property value exists in another Array

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am trying to achieve the following task with `lodash` or pure JS.

I have an Array of Objects which I filter by a given property value

```
let res = _.filter(array, {obj.property: "somevalue"}
```

Now I have another Array like so `[val1, val2,val3]` which I want the filtered array properties to compare with like so.

```
let res = _.filter(array, {obj.property1: "somevalue", obj.property2: existsInOtherArray}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example with the input and expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a set and the filter method of array like:

```js
const array = [
  {property1: 'somevalue'},
  {property1: 'somevalue', property2: 'val2'}
]

const set = new Set(['val1', 'val2', 'val3'])
const res = array.filter(obj => obj.property1 === 'somevalue'
                                && set.has(obj.property2))

console.log(res)
```